# How to print only 1 item from a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.7

I've recently just started learning Python and usally find answers to my problems online but can't seem to get the right solution for this one. 
I created a dictionary with 3 contacts and i want to print 1 contact from the list using an if statement.

```
contacts = {
    "John" : 938477566,
    "Jack" : 938377264,
    "Jill" : 947662781
}
```

`if "John" in contacts:
    print ("Contact details: %s %i" % contacts.items()[0])`

This is the output I am looking for:

> Contact details: John 938477566

But i keep getting this

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\user\Documents\asega\python\objectsclasses\exercise3.py", line 31, in 
>       print ("Contact details: %s %i" % contacts.items()[0])
>   TypeError: 'dict_items' object does not support indexing

Thanks

Comment: do `print("Contact details: %s %i" %  ("John", contacts["John"]))`

Comment: or `contacts.get("John")` or `contacts.get("John", some_default_value)`.

Comment: @DanielMesejo remove the `%s`: `print("Contact details: %i" % contacts["John"])`

Comment: @Jonas I believe is correct the way it is.

Comment: @DanielMesejo oops never mind, sry I missed the part, where you added the "John" string

Answer (score 4):

`contacts.items()` returns pairs of key-value. In your case, that would be something like

```
(("John", 938477566), ("Jack", 938377264), ("Jill", 947662781))
```

Except that in python 3 this is like a generator and not a list. So you'd have to do `list(contacts.items())` if you wanted to index it, which explains your error message. However, even if you did `list(contacts.items())[0]`, as discussed above, you'd get the first pair of key-value.

What you're trying to do is fetch the value of a key if said key exists and `contacts.get(key, value_if_key_doesnt_exist)` does that for you.

```
contact = 'John'
# we use 0 for the default value because it's falsy,
# but you'd have to ensure that 0 wouldn't naturally occur in your values
# or any other falsy value, for that matter.
details = contacts.get(contact, 0)
if details:
    print('Contact details: {} {}'.format(contact, details))
else:
    print('Contact not found')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this. If you are sure that 'John' is in the dictionary, there is no need of if statement. In other way, you can write it.. your choice

```
contacts = {
    "John" : 938477566,
    "Jack" : 938377264,
    "Jill" : 947662781
}
print("Contact details: %s %i" % ("John", contacts["John"]))
```

Comment: Same as my previous comment will throw key error if 'John' is not found in `dict`

Comment: Then you just add if statement. I wrote it in my answer, if you did not sure that john is in dictionary, write some if statement.

Answer (score -1):

No need to check in `if` condition just use `get` to get the corresponding value and return `-1` if key is not present

```
contacts = {
    "John" : 938477566,
    "Jack" : 938377264,
    "Jill" : 947662781
}

contacts.get('John',-1) # -1 will be returned if key is not found
```

Print formatting

```
name_to_search='John'
print("Contact details: %s %i" % (name_to_search, contacts.get(name_to_search,-1)))
```

Or

```
name_to_search='John'
print("Contact details: {} {}" .format(name_to_search, contacts.get(name_to_search,-1)))
```

Comment: op wants to print

Comment: It's nice to see an example of the `.get` function for a dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

First of all its dictionary not a list , you can access the elements from a list by indexing , and it is not possible in dictionary, 
you can access the elements by key

```
contacts = {
    "John" : 938477566,
    "Jack" : 938377264,
    "Jill" : 947662781
}

for k,v in contacts.items():
    print(k,v)
```

or 
contacts['John'] you can access the value

Comment: use `print(f"Contact details: {k} {v}")` to print.

Comment: It will be an overkill to iterate over all the dictionary items if we just need to get one element. When we can use dictionary for O(1) why do we need to go for O(n)

Comment: To add to my previous comment, `contacts['John']` will throw key error if 'John' key is not present in the dictionary. Also *it is not possible in dictionary* is ambiguous as it is possible in Python2.7 in which `contacts.items()` will be a list while in Python3 it will be a generator object and you just need to cast the dict_items object to a `list`.

Answer (score -2):

Dictionaries do not support indexing so to print "John" you cant index it however the following code may word:

```
if "John" in contacts:
   print("Contact details:","John",contacts["John"])
```

Hope it helps